# Confusing python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I'm trying to figure out how this list comprehension works, but I can't quite understand how it works. If somebody could write the non-list-comprehension equivalent I think I could understand.

This is the line I'm stuck on:

```
[item for sublist in li for item in sublist]
```

It's stated purpose is to flatted out multidimensional lists. Here's an example of me testing it:

```
>>> li = [[0,1],[1,3,5],[4,5,3,2]]
>>> [item for sublist in li for item in sublist]
[0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Non-list comprehension equivalent:

```
arr = []
for sublist in li:
    for item in sublist:
        arr.append( item )
```

Comment: Note that the two are semantically equivalent but the list comprehension will generally perform better.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent for loop version would look like:

```
result = []

for sublist in li:
    for item in sublist:
        result.append(item)
```

So, the order of `for` statements in the list comprehension is equivalent to the order in which they will appear in the nested for statement.